# best useEffect-setup for fetching data depending on different dependencies

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect

I need a performant way to fetch data depending on different dependencies.

So, fetchPosts needs to run:

- on load
- when currentPage is changed
- when currentTimeline is changed

**and**, when currentTimeline is changed, the currentPage needs to be set to 0 again, to start from scratch.

So what happens now:
The fetchposts gets called multiple times on load, which causes a massive amount of requests on the database.

Question:

- how could I solve this, that it only calls the fetchPosts on load and only when currentpage/currentTimeline is changed.
  And when currentTimeline is changed, the currentpage gets set to 0.

```
/* eslint-disable react-hooks/exhaustive-deps */
// @flow

import style from "./style.module.scss";
import React, { useState, useEffect, Suspense } from "react";
import { Grid, NoSsr } from "@material-ui/core";
import { Post as PostComponent } from "@components";
import type { Post } from "@types";
import { getPosts, addPosts } from "../../api/Posts";
import { TimelineFooter, PostCreation } from "@components";
import { Box } from "@material-ui/core";
import InfiniteScroll from "react-infinite-scroll-component";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import { timelineState } from "@atoms";
import { useRecoilValue } from "recoil";
import { deletePost } from "../../api/Posts";
/**
 * Timeline
 */

function Timeline() {
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
    const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
    const [hasMore, setHasMore] = useState(true);
    const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(0);
    const currentTimeline = useRecoilValue(timelineState);

    const fetchPosts = () => {
        getPosts(currentTimeline.tab, currentPage).then((result: *) => {
            if (result.length > 0) {
                setPosts(posts.concat(result));
                setHasMore(true);
            } else {
                setHasMore(false);
            }
        });
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("current page");
        fetchPosts();
    }, [currentPage]);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("current currentTimeline");

        setPosts([]);
        setCurrentPage(0);
    }, [currentTimeline]);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("posts en currentpage");
        if (posts.length === 0) {
            if (currentPage !== 0) {
                setCurrentPage(0);
            } else {
                fetchPosts();
            }
        }
    }, [posts, currentPage]);

    const fetchMoreData = () => {
        setCurrentPage(currentPage + 1);
    };

    const handleClickOpen = () => {
        setOpen(true);
    };
    const handleClose = () => {
        setOpen(false);
    };

    const handlePostCreation = (message: string, files: Array<*>) => {
        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("content", message);
        if (files) {
            for (const file of files) {
                formData.append("files", file);
            }
        }
        formData.append("timelineCategory", currentTimeline.tab);
        formData.append("regionName", "General");
        addPosts(formData)
            .then(() => {
                setPosts([]);
            })
            .then(handleClose);
    };

    const onDeletePost = uuid => {
        deletePost(uuid).then(() => {
            const newposts = posts.filter(item => item.uuid !== uuid);
            setPosts(newposts);
        });
    };

    return (
        <>
            <Box pl={2} pr={2}>
                <Grid container justify="center" className={style.fullWidth}>
                    <NoSsr>
                        <InfiniteScroll
                            style={{ width: "100%" }}
                            dataLength={posts.length}
                            next={fetchMoreData}
                            hasMore={hasMore}
                            loader={
                                <Box p={2} textAlign="center">
                                    <Typography variant="subtitle2">
                                        Meer laden...
                                    </Typography>
                                </Box>
                            }
                            endMessage={
                                <Box p={2} textAlign="center">
                                    <Typography variant="subtitle2">
                                        Alle berichten geladen.
                                    </Typography>
                                </Box>
                            }
                        >
                            <Suspense
                                fallback={
                                    <span>Gebruikergegevens inladen...</span>
                                }
                            >
                                {posts.map((item: Post) => (
                                    <Grid item xs={12} key={item.uuid}>
                                        <PostComponent
                                            post={item}
                                            onDeletePost={onDeletePost}
                                        />
                                    </Grid>
                                ))}
                            </Suspense>
                        </InfiniteScroll>
                    </NoSsr>
                </Grid>
            </Box>
            <TimelineFooter handleClickOpen={handleClickOpen} />
            <PostCreation
                open={open}
                handleClose={handleClose}
                handlePostCreation={handlePostCreation}
            />
        </>
    );
}

export default Timeline;
```

Comment: Seems the single dependency on `currentPage` is sufficient to meet your requirements. When `currentTimeline` updates use an `useEffect` to "reset" the `currentPage` state which will trigger the fetch (*which it seems your code also does*). How are you auditing the fetch requests?

Answer (score 2):

#### 1. Infinite useEffect call.

You are calling fetch repeatedly because of this useEffect call (or, at least, this useEffect call).

1. You are running a useEffect with `posts` as dependency, while in your `fetchPosts`, you are calling `setPosts`, which triggers this useEffect, causing an **infinite loop**.

   ```
   useEffect(() => {
        console.log("posts en currentpage");
        if (posts.length === 0) {
            if (currentPage !== 0) {
                setCurrentPage(0);
            } else {
                fetchPosts(); //<--- this triggers setPosts which triggers this useEffect call.
            }
        }
    }, [posts, currentPage]);
   ```
2. This useEffect also triggers `setCurrentPage(0)` (which also triggers this `useEffect`) also triggers `fetchPosts` which also triggers `setPosts` which causes this to **run indefinitely**.

**In Summary** - is this `useEffect` necessary?

#### 2. Unnecessary useEffect call.

The following may seem like a very normal use of useEffect in many situations, and looks very convenient, but it gets out of hand/control sometimes - E.g. your current situation, where you are manipulating your `currentPage` base on different conditions.

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("current page");
    fetchPosts();
}, [currentPage]);
```

You could have put your fetchPosts() here.

```
   const fetchMoreData = () => {
        setCurrentPage(currentPage + 1);
        fetchPosts(currentPage +1);
    };
```

and here

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("current currentTimeline");

    setPosts([]);
    setCurrentPage(0);
    fetchPosts(0);
}, [currentTimeline]);
```

Of course, you will need to update your fetchPost function to conditionally take in a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You could start by making some minor improvements like using the state update function to update currentPage as its value depends on previous state.
This way is recommended by react.
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate

```
const fetchMoreData = () => {
  setCurrentPage(prevCurrentPage => prevCurrentPage + 1);
};
```

Comment inside this hook indicates thats it is for 'posts on current page'.
However 'posts' looks to be an array of total posts rather than posts per page.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    console.log("posts en currentpage");
    if (posts.length === 0) {
        if (currentPage !== 0) {
           setCurrentPage(0);
        } else {
           fetchPosts();
        }
     }
  }, [posts, currentPage]);
```

The above hook will also execute on mount as initially posts will be empty and currentPage will be 0.
So on load itself 'fetchPosts' will be called twice.
If you intend to keep track of all posts per page then you may want to rethink the logic here.